# What should I request the Gmail API to get email statistics?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail

I am interested in getting the number of emails sent and received(in priority inbox) on the current day. Nothing more.

Using the REST API in Google App Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/your_email%40gmail.com/messages?labelIds=SENT&q=newer_than%3A1d&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

To get the number of messages received/sent in the last 24 hours, you can use the [`gmail.users.messages.list` API.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) You must specify the following query: `newer_than:1d` to only get a list of emails that were recieved/sent in the past 24 hours. You must also specify which label to query in (`INBOX` or `SENT`). Please refer to the following screenshot. You can test it out for yourself [here.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it)

[image: Gmail API Configuration]

Comment: I figured this out on my own. To get priority inbox count, I used `is:important`. The count can be found in the `resultSizeEstimate` key of the response. However, I am not sure why it is an estimate.