# Sending a gmail message

Tags: python-3.x, base64, gmail-api

im trying to send a gmail message with the following code:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import base64
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    """Create a message for an email.

    Args:
        sender: Email address of the sender.
        to: Email address of the receiver.
        subject: The subject of the email message.
        message_text: The text of the email message.

    Returns:
        An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
    """
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    #return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
    b64_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
    b64_string = b64_bytes.decode()
    #body = {'raw': b64_string}
    return {'raw': b64_string}


s = "email"
t = "email"
sub = "test subject"
m = "message test"

create_message(s,t,sub,m)
```

where s = my email(replaced with "email" in this example and t = my other email (again replaced))
It doesnt kick out any errors but doesnt send the message.
Also this code didnt work:
`#return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}` 
as it produced the following error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` 
"I solved that" with this:

```
b64_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
 b64_string = b64_bytes.decode()
 #body = {'raw': b64_string}
 return {'raw': b64_string}
```

edit(1): I do have credentials.json and passed the google api example

Comment: Have you checked the Gmail API logs to see if any errors occurred? EDIT: This may help with checking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377226/what-should-i-request-the-gmail-api-to-get-email-statistics

Comment: cant find my token and the logs are empty :/

Comment: @SamMorgan seems like i forgot to do messages.send() do you perhaps have any idea how that works? the docs are very confusing for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to create client_secret.json and paste my credentials there, ctrc+c, ctrl+v an old example and update it to python 3.x, resolved base 64 issue and it works :)

```
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client import file
try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatability with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

import base64
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes
from httplib2 import Http

from apiclient import errors

from apiclient.discovery import build
credentials = get_credentials()
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
  """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
               .execute())
    print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64 encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  b64_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
  b64_string = b64_bytes.decode()
  #body = {'raw': b64_string}
  return {'raw': b64_string}
  #return {'raw': base64.b64encode(message.as_string())}

testMessage = CreateMessage("email","email","test_subject","test_message")

testSend = SendMessage(service, 'me', testMessage)
```

emails replaced with email in line 106 (second from bottom)